# How to display ionic2 Alert after Firebase changeEmail

Tags: firebase, ionic2

I have the following function to change the email on a Firebase user account. I want to display an ionic2 alert when complete, whether it was successful or there was an error. From my code below I do get the alert to display BUT it is blank. Most likely it is a timing issue on the Firebase promise but I don't know how to fix it.

```
private doChangeEmail(data): void {

var myAlert: {
  title?: string, 
  subtitle?: string
} = {};

this.auth.ref.changeEmail({
  oldEmail: data.oldemail,
  newEmail: data.newemail,
  password: data.password
}, function(error) {
  if (error) {
    switch (error.code) {
      case "INVALID_PASSWORD":
        myAlert.title = 'Invalid Password';
        myAlert.subtitle = 'The specified user account password is incorrect.';
        break;
      case "INVALID_USER":
        myAlert.title = 'Invalid User';
        myAlert.subtitle = 'The specified user account does not exist.';
        break;
      default:
        myAlert.title = 'Error creating user';
        myAlert.subtitle = error;
    }
  } else {
    myAlert.title = 'DONE';
    myAlert.subtitle = 'User email changed successfully!';
  }
});

let alert = Alert.create({
  title: myAlert.title,
  subTitle: myAlert.subtitle,
  buttons: [{
    text: 'OK',
    handler: () => {
    }
  }]
});
this.nav.present(alert);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the following comment by Frank van Puffelen which solved my issue:

**You're using `this` inside a callback function, where it has a different meaning. One solution is to use fat-arrow/rocket notation for the callback, which ensures this is what you expect it to be:**

The correct syntax should be

```
this.auth.ref.changeEmail({
  oldEmail: data.oldemail,
  newEmail: data.newemail,
  password: data.password
}, (error) => {
  if (error){
     // do error stuff..
  } else {
     // do success stuff..
  }
  // show alert here...
})
```

and the alert shows correclty as pointed out by Aaron Saunders

Answer (score 0):

put the alert code inside the promise result....

```
this.auth.ref.changeEmail({
  oldEmail: data.oldemail,
  newEmail: data.newemail,
  password: data.password
}, function(error) {
  if (error){
     // do error stuff..
  } else {
     // do success stuff..
  }
  // show alert here...
})
```

Comment: I tried that already but I get 'EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot read property 'nav' of undefined'

Comment: In my code sample above the Alert DOES show up but is blank